# Extract differences of CSV files into a seperate file

Tags: powershell, csv, compare

I have a CSV file (with headers) filled with assortment data. The file will be updated once every day. I need to find the differences in those files (the old and the new one) and extract them into a separate file.

For instance: in the old file there could be a price of "18,50" and now it's an updated one of "17,90". The script should now extract this row into a new file.

So far, I was able to import both CSV files (via `Import-Csv`) but my current solution is to compare each row by `findstr`.

The problems are:

- In 9 of 10 cases the strings are too long to compare.
- What if a new row will be inserted - I guess the comparison wouldn't work any longer if the row isn't inserted at the end of the file.

My current code is:

```
foreach ($oldData in (Import-Csv $PSScriptRoot\old.csv -Delimiter ";" -Encoding "default")) {
    foreach ($newData in (Import-Csv $PSScriptRoot\new.csv -Delimiter ";" -Encoding "default")) {
        findstr.exe /v /c:$oldData $newData > $PSScriptRoot\diff.txt
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: And some sample data. ie. is there an identifying column (product # for example)?

Comment: Yes there is an identifying column called "idArtikel" which is the unique product-id

Comment: You could read both files into hash tables (https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/7064dc22-0611-4f4c-a846-dc24ed344389/comparing-hashtables?forum=winserverpowershell), and then compare the hash tables (https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/7064dc22-0611-4f4c-a846-dc24ed344389/comparing-hashtables?forum=winserverpowershell)

Comment: Another information: one line could contain 3000 characters or more (thats why I got problems with `findstr`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read both files into separate variables and use [`Compare-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object?view=powershell-3.0) for the comparison:

```
$fields = 'idArtikel', 'Preis', ...

$csv1 = Import-Csv $PSScriptRoot\old.csv -Delimiter ';'
$csv2 = Import-Csv $PSScriptRoot\new.csv -Delimiter ';'

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $csv1 -DifferenceObject $csv2 -Property $fields -PassThru | Where-Object {
    $_.SideIndicator -eq '=>'
} | Select-Object $fields | Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\diff.csv' -Delimiter ';'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$csv1 | Join $csv2 idArtikel -Merge {$Right.$_} | Export-CSV 'C:\path\to\diff.csv' -Delimiter ';'
```

For details on `Join` (`Join-Object`), see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483110/1701026